# Proof for order of composition for permutations on indices into a sequence

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Suppose I have a sequence $s$ that contains some elements in a well-defined order. Furthermore, let $i$ be an integer (an index into the sequence) and $s[i]$ shall denote the $i$-th element from $s$.

We now define two permutations $a$ and $b$ that shall act on $s$. The action (written e.g. $s^a$) is defined as $s^a[i] = s[i^a]$. That is, the $i$-th element in the reordered sequence is the element that had index $i^a$ (image of $i$ under $a$) in the original sequence $s$.

Through examples (playing around with SymPy) and through online research, I know that $s^{ab}[i] = s[i^{ba}]$ (where e.g. $i^{ba} = (i^b)^a$). Therefore, the order in which the permutations have to be applied to the object reverses between applying it to the entire sequence vs. applying it to the index into the original sequence.

I have no reason to doubt this fact, but I in order to get a better understanding of how things work, I wanted to proof this relation ($s^{ab}[i] = s[i^{ba}]$). However, I am unsure how one would go about this. Any help will be appreciated.

---

Concrete example:
Let's start with
$$s = [ \overset{0}{\mathstrut a}, \overset{1}{\mathstrut b}, \overset{2}{\mathstrut c}, \overset{3}{\mathstrut d} ]
$$
where the integer over the individual entries are the element's index in the original sequence $s$.

If $a = (0,2,1,3)$, then
$$
s^a = [ \overset{2}{\mathstrut c}, \overset{3}{\mathstrut d}, \overset{1}{\mathstrut b}, \overset{0}{\mathstrut a} ]
$$

If in addition $b = (0,1,3)$, we find that
$$
s^{ab} = [ \overset{3}{\mathstrut d}, \overset{0}{\mathstrut a}, \overset{1}{\mathstrut b}, \overset{2}{\mathstrut c} ]
$$

However (using left-to-right ordering) $a \cdot b = (0,2,3,1)$, which has an image representation of $[2,3,0,1]$, which is not the order of indices into the original sequence $s$ that we need to construct $s^{ab}$.

$b \cdot a = (0,3,2,1)$ though, which has an image representation of $[3,0,1,2]$, which corresponds to our "manual derivation" for $s^{ab}$ from above.

Comment: Is there any connection with/translation into the standard permutation formalism (say $S_4$, in your example)?

Comment: @Devo what do you mean by "standard permutation formalism"? The one where you are only concerned about bijections from a set of n numbers onto itself? Effectively, that is  the domain in which the composition of the used permutations is performed in. The only difference being how to interpret / what to do with the final permutation that comes out of the calculation.

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: $s$ is not a permutation but a list of elements. $a$ and $b$ are then permutations on the $n$ elements of that list (which in my example happen to be letters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to understanding why $s^{ab}[i] = s[i^{ba}]$ and not $s[i^{ab}]$ is to write down what it means for permutation $b$ acting on $s^a$. So let's be explicit here:

$$
s^a[i] = s[i^a]
$$

Therefore, we can explicitly write down
$$
s^{ab}[i] = s^a[i^b] = s^a[k] = s[k^a] = s[(i^b)^a] = s[i^{ba}]
$$
Here, we have intermittently introduced a helper variable $k = i^b$ that describes the image of $i$ under $b$ in order to increase readability and to better illustrate what is happening. With $k$ at hand, it is straight forward to insert the definition of $s^a[i]$ into our equation and by back-substituting the definition of $k$ into our equation, we arrive at the desired result.

Comment: The answer to my question came to my while explicitly typing out my question. I decided to share the question along with my answer anyway with the hope that someone else that might struggle with this might benefit from this in the future.